# How can a tandoor oven cook skewered meat evenly

Tags: equipment, meat, heat, skewers

I am going to build or buy a tandoor. Before I invest, I have done some research into how to cook in one.

The part that confuses me is, all the video's I have seen, show the skewers in the tandoor that are nearly vertical as per this picture.

[image]

In my mind, this would make it impossible to cook evenly enough given the meat at the bottom of the skewer is closer to the heat source and as such, will cook much faster compared to the meat closer to the lid (that is further away from the heat source).

I'm not aiming for perfection with my question, meaning, I don't expect every piece of food to cook 100% perfectly / evenly etc. [One video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2C241RVclTw) (at 7:50) I've seen even shows that the meat at the top was a higher temperature compared to the meat near the heat source.

My question is, how can this cook so evenly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called a tandoor *oven*, not a tandoor *grill* or a tandoor hotplate. It is enclosed, and with thick walls, which means heat is coming from the sides too, not only the bottom. Also, there is convection, and with a lid on, the hot air doesn't escape.

In short, it is the same principle as any other oven.